# How can I list files in category - with streaming, so command starts showing something quickly also if folder has millions of files

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory

I have folder that apparently has millions of files inside it.

As result, `dir` command is running for minutes already without displaying anything.

I checked `dir --help` and tried to search for solution.

How can I list files in category - with streaming, so command starts showing something quickly also if folder has millions of files?

I have no idea what is in the affected folder.

Comment: Try `ls -1f` ...

Comment: ... Or try `find`

Comment: But `find` would require you know part of the filename if you should display it in "chunks", right?

Comment: @pLumo `ls -1f` works! Feel free to make into an answer larger or smaller

Comment: @Raffa `find` also worked! Also feel free to post answer and I will at least upvote it.

Comment: @ArturMeinild apparently `find` can be used without arguments.

Comment: Thanks reducingactivity ... I'm glad it worked ... `find` doesn't sort by default i.e. first come first served ... While `ls` and `dir` sort files *alphabetically* by default and this delays the output but can be disabled by the option `-f` so `ls -f` and `dir -f` ... Both are small details but will make better answer when combined together ... @pLumo was the first to comment so please pLumo go ahead.

Comment: oh, somehow I never noticed that `dir` sorts - that would explain why trying to list several million files was not working well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` will sort its output alphabetically by default, so it needs to read the content of the whole directory, before it is shown.

You can avoid sorting by running `ls` with `-U`.

But, `ls` will also read the type of each file/directory to be able to color it. This has also an impact on the performance. Avoid this with `-f` flag.

```
-f     do not sort, enable -aU, disable -ls --color
```

I usually use

```
ls -1f
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193/quick-ls-command)

Comment: what `1` is doing here?

Comment: So the one column may be easily piped to another command which then doesn't have to parse output lines of multiple files.

Comment: @ubfan1 afaik ls only outputs multiple columns when standard output is a terminal, not a pipe (*"... otherwise, the output is listed one per line and control characters are output as-is."* - according to `info ls`)